# Teradata SQL -Min Max transaction dates from Rows

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

Tried Qualify row_Number () and Qualify Min & Max functions but still not able to get range of dates for transaction. See data structure below

[image]

Need help for the following output

[image]

Thank you in advance

Comment: What are the rules for combining rows? Consecutive dates per ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the groups of consecutive dates first. There are several ways to do this, in your case the best should is based on comparing a sequence to another sequence with gaps in it:

```
with cte as
 (
   select t.*
      -- consecutive numbers = sequence without gaps
     ,row_number()
      over (partition by location, cust#, cust_type -- ??
            order by transaction_date) as rn
      -- consecutive numbers as long as there's no missing date = sequence with gaps
     ,(transaction_date - date '0001-01-01') as rn2

      -- assign a common (but meaningless) value to consecutive dates,
      -- value changes when there's a gap
     ,rn2 - rn as grp
   from tab as t
 )
select location, cust#, cust_type -- ??
  ,min(transaction_date), max(transaction_date)
  ,min(amount), max(amount)
from cte
 -- add the calculated "grp" to GROUP BY 
group by location, cust#, cust_type, grp
```

The columns used for PARTITION BY/GROUP BY depend on your rules.

Comment: Done and explained amazingly. Thank you Sir!!! It gave me the exact output.